# No dating social apps in the Play Store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, android-emulator

I installed Android Studio for testing purposes and checked the Nexus 5 and Nexus 5X device images for the emulator. One thing I've noticed is that there are no dating social apps available in the Play Store like Badoo, Tinder, OkCupid, etc. you get the idea.

Is this because of some settings that I haven't configured or are these apps blocked for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, it was an issue with the Google account I used in the emulator. It didn't have permissions to 18+ content.